# Are the eigenvalues of Hecke operators distinct?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Given a Hecke operator which acts on the space of modular forms for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, are the eigenvalues necessarily distinct?

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a modular form for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with a vanishing Hecke eigenvalue.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if a particular Hecke operator $T_\ell$ acting on the space $M_k(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ of forms of fixed weight $k$ for the full modular group has distinct eigenvalues (i.e. square-free characteristic polynomial)?

Comment: My understanding is that the Hecke eigenvalue is the trace of Frobenius on the Galois representation of the corresponding elliptic curve and so is bounded by $2\sqrt{l}$ and integral, so by the pidgeonhole principle the eigenvalues must fail to be distinct for $k$ large enough. Similarly a Hecke eigenvalue $0$ would correspond to an elliptic curve with exactly $p+1$ points over $\mathbb F_p$, like $y^2=x^3-x$ over $\mathbb F_3$.

Comment: @Will:  That bound is right in weight $2$, but in general the bound for weight $k$ is $2p^{(k-1)/2}$.

Comment: Alright because he's generalizing the weight rather than the subgroup. Then I don't know.

Comment: It's conjectured (Maeda's conjecture) that for any prime $p$ and any even weight $k \ge 12$, the characteristic polynomial of $T_p$ acting on $S_k(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$; in particular, it has no multiple roots. Various authors (eg Buzzard, Kleinerman) have verified this for lots of values of $p$ and $k$. If I remember correctly, in all cases that have been tested the stronger statement holds that the char polys all have Galois group equal to the full symmetric group of the appropriate degree.

Comment: The way I understand the question: is it true that for any Hecke eigenform $f\in S_k(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ the Hecke eigenvalues $\lambda_f(p)$, normalized so that they lie between $\pm 2p^{(k-1)/2}$, are all distinct?

Comment: Interesting question. When you say "Hecke operators", does it mean
$T_n$ with $n$ integer or $T_p$ with $p$ prime ? Or is it equivalent
in this question, for some simple reason ?

Comment: If Meada's conjecture is true for some $n$, then all multiple roots have same multiplicity. If  the Galois group of the characteristic polynomial for $T_n$ of  is $S_d$ ($d=\deg f$), then  the characteristic polynomial for $T_n$ is either irreducible or of the form $(x-a)^d$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq1}a_f(n)e^{2\pi i n z}$ be a holomorphic cuspidal Hecke eigenform of even weight $k\geq 12$ on the full modular group with $a_f(1)=1$, with $|a_f(p)|\leq 2p^{\frac{k-1}{2}}$.  A conjecture of Atkin and Serre proposes that for every prime $p$,

$|a_f(p)|\gg_{\epsilon} p^{\frac{k-3}{2}-\epsilon}$,

from which it would follow by multiplicativity that the map $n\mapsto a_f(n)$ is finite-to-1.  In this direction, Murty and Murty (http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1987__115__391_0.pdf) proved that there exists an effective constant $c>0$ such that $|a_f(n)|>(\log n)^c$ when $a_f(n)$ is odd.  Their result also extends to $f$ on congruence subgroups.  Assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis for Hecke $L$-functions, one can replace $(\log n)^c$ with $n^c$ on a subset of the integers of natural density 1.